# Change from datetime to date in the session variable using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 txtdob.Text = Session["DOB"].ToString();
```

It is displaying both date and time,I need only date to be printed,Is there any type of code that makes to display only date within the code i have mention above.?

If i execute the above code it gives the date format as
            9/9/2013 12:00:00 AM

But i just need    9/9/2013

In the database DOB has a datatype of DateTime.

I tried with every line of code you have suggested but its giving  error as Specified cast is not valid

session["DOB"] is stored as

```
 Session["DOB"] = ds.Tables["login_det"].Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString();
```

Do i need to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 txtdob.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["DOB"].ToString()).Date.ToShortDateString();
```

OR

```
 txtdob.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["DOB"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 5):

If `Session["DOB"]` is a DateTime instance you could [`specify the format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
txtdob.Text = ((DateTime)Session["DOB"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

If it is not DateTime, but a string, then you will have to modify the code that is storing this value into the session so that it either stores the DateTime or it formats the string the way you want it to be.

Comment: its datetime @Darin but its giving error as  Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Then it's not DateTime!!!! As explained in my answer in this case you will have to modify the code that is storing the value into the Session.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
txtdob.Text =  Convert.ToDateTime(Session["DOB"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

or you can find more formats [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)